# C++ Multithreading program example using multiple terminals in the same computer

Tags: c++, multithreading, pthreads

I am new to multithreaded programming. I am trying to run a program using two terminals in one laptop. Wherein, in these two terminals it should be registered as user1 and user2 and before the 2 programs start running, one of them should wait for the other using "thread" or "pthread"(I don't know the difference). If the user1 will enter any message to the terminal1, it should also be displayed to user2 in terminal2. 
And I have no idea how to start the code even after researching about threading for so many times. Please help. Thank you in advance.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

using namespace std;

void msg1(string msg) {
    cout << "user1 says: " << msg << endl;
}
void msg2(string msg) {
    cout << "user2 says: " << msg << endl;
}
int main() {
    string message1, message2;
    cin >> message1;
    thread t1(msg1, message1);
    t1.join();
    cin >> message2;
    thread t2(msg2, message2);
    t2.join();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please show us some code you already tried.

Comment: `#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

using namespace std;

void msg1(string msg) {
    cout << "user1 says: " << msg << endl;
}
void msg2(string msg) {
    cout << "user2 says: " << msg << endl;
}
int main() {
    string message1, message2;
    cin >> message1;
    thread t1(msg1, message1);
    t1.join();
    cin >> message2;
    thread t2(msg2, message2);
    t2.join();
    return 0;
}`

Comment: not in comments, but edit your question and put the code there. Read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: sorry, I was not able to find the edit button on my post earlier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to achieve too much at once, using threads and using multiple terminals.

The latter is easy, if you only need output: Just write the content to a file and run `tailf filename` in a terminale, which follow the contents of the file. You can use e.g. an `std::fstream` to keep the familiar interface of `std::cout`.

If you need input, things get a bit more complicated. In that case, you need to open a two-directional connection between a terminal window and the program. The communication channel would be e.g. TCP or some local transport. Using TCP, you could simply use `telnet` to connect to the program.

Concerning threads, just read any random C++ 11 tutorial on them. You could also check out the documentation of Boost.Thread, where the standard threads originated from. In any case, you will have to do some research on the topics here yourself, I'm only trying to point you in the right direction.